# apk file not display on homescreen

Tags: android, apk

I've got some sample project.

When i run it on my machine, successfully compile and show below msg on console,

```
[2012-06-30 12:44:03 - VoiceNotes] Uploading VoiceNotes.apk onto device 'HT96WKF01301'
[2012-06-30 12:44:03 - VoiceNotes] Installing VoiceNotes.apk...
[2012-06-30 12:44:06 - VoiceNotes] Success!
[2012-06-30 12:44:06 - VoiceNotes] \VoiceNotes\bin\VoiceNotes.apk installed on device
[2012-06-30 12:44:06 - VoiceNotes] Done!
```

but not found the apk file on my device screen,

When i check on settings -> application->manage application, the apk file is there.

where it has been loacated and how to run on device?

Comment: it's not even with other app in application grid section ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that you have to mentioned Launcher in your manifest file.

Check your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity
   android:name=".YourMainActivityNameHere"
   android:label="@string/app_name">
       <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
</activity>
```